# Squeaking noise on bushings. What kind of oil should be used.?

Tags: suspension

Recently my Toyota 2010 model started to emit noise when I'm driving slowly. A mechanic sprayed WD40 on the bushings and the noise was gone. But after three days the noise returned.

Comment: A photo of where he sprayed the WD40 would be useful.

Comment: Please, @Moab could you answer the question to the proper place? Thank you...

Comment: Using oil based lubricant on rubber or plastic parts is bad. The oil degrades the elastomer. I’m assuming your bushings are either rubber or polyurethane. My guess is dirt in the joint is the cause of your squeak. Best is to use vegetable or silicone based grease but I suspect soapy water would also provide some relief.

Comment: It is mainly polyurethane bushings that squeak. Rubber bushings are more expensive but quieter.

Answer (score 0):

Ru-Glyde is the best safest rubber lubricant, but is only sold in gallon bottles.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000CIJUGK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000CIJUGK)

Comment: Not sure about this aftermarket stuff, but the tire mounting lubricant used by automotive manufacturers provides lubrication to aid tire installation to rim, but then it dries tacky (by design)  If this is the same stuff, not a great option to prevent squeaky bushings.

Comment: Been using it for 35 years, it works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is dirt in the joint is the cause of your squeak. I’m assuming your bushings are either rubber or polyurethane. You could lube the bushings with  vegetable based or silicone based grease but I suspect soapy water would also provide some relief. Using oil based lubricant on rubber or plastic parts is bad. The oil degrades the elastomer.

And its not totally clear on what parts were sprayed (Bushings on front struts / shocks? front A-arm bushings? Stabilizer bar mounts?)   Exactly what parts are we talking about?